# Find relationship between $y$, $x$ and $z$

Tags: regression, rational-functions

A certain $y$ is determined by $x$ and $z$.

If I would keep $z$ constant at $80$, the relationship between $y$ and $x$ is
    $$y=17,0722/x.$$
If I would keep $x$ constant at $1$, the relationship between $y$ and $z$ is

$$y=(-0,3712\cdot z+1395,83)/(z+0,0177).$$

Is there a way to find the relationship between $y$, $x$ and $z$?

Comment: Do you by chance know multivariate calculus?

Comment: I don't. Could you point me in the right direction to solve this problem?

Comment: Already by checking the second relationship and replacing $z=80$, I don't get exactly the first relationship with replacing $X=1$

Comment: Indeed. Both relationships come from data. The first one is accurate, since I knew it was of a rational form. The second one I had to guess. Assuming this one is rational two, that is the formula the software calculated, but it's not very reliable I've noticed.

Answer (score 0):

No, not without further information: You could define $y$ by your given equations and take it to by whatever you want at, say $x = 60$, $z = 60$, without interfering with what happens at $x = 1$ or at $z = 80$. As a side remark, your two relationships give slightly different results when $x = 1$ and $z=80$ (the first one giving $17,0722$, and the second one something closer to $17,073$).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My guess is that there is a rational relationship behind this problem. If it would've been lineair, I could find the relationship y=ax+bz+c using multiple lineair regression analysis. Is there anything like it, but for rational relationships? I have lot's of data for y, x and z, I just can't find how y is calculated...